# Javascript deleting from database/fading the table row away

Tags: javascript

First of all i didn't know how to specify the title sorry for that.

I have a pretty messy code but basically this is what it should do.
When the delete button is pressed the whole tr should fade away. Currently only the last td with the button in it fades away. I tried replacing the a at

```
$('a').click(function(){
```

with tr. But when i do that the row will dissapear but it wont delete in the database.
Does anyone know a sollution? Thanks in advance

ps: Sorry for my english and the badly displayed coded.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $.post('delete.php', {id:del_id},function(data){
        parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
        });
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content1"></div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table" class="sortable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="nosort"><h3>ID</h3></th>
                <th><h3>Merk</h3></th>
                <th><h3>Type</h3></th>
                <th><h3>Imei</h3></th>
                <th><h3>Serienummer</h3></th>
                <th><h3>Kleur</h3></th>
                <th><h3>Locatie</h3></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
                include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
                $sql = "select *
                        FROM units";
                $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);       
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['merk']}{$row['type']}{$row['imei']}{$row['serienr']}{$row['kleur']}{$row['locatie']}<a href=\"javascript:return(0);\" id=\"{$row['id']}\"><img src=\"images\delete_icon.gif\" height=\"12px\" width=\"12px\"/></a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }       
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['merk']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['type']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['imei']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['serienr']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['kleur']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['locatie']."</td>";
                                ?>
                                <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('test1.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>', 'newwindow', 'width=400, height=600'); return false;"><img src="images/gtk-edit.png"/></a></td>

                                <?php

                                echo "</tr>";
                            }


                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                  </table>
        <div id="controls">
            <div id="perpage">
                <select onchange="sorter.size(this.value)">
                <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
                    <option value="10" >10</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="100">100</option>
                </select>
                <span>Weergeven per pagina</span>
            </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                <img src="images/first.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1,true)" />
                <img src="images/previous.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1)" />
                <img src="images/next.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(1)" />
                <img src="images/last.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Last Page" onclick="sorter.move(1,true)" />
            </div>
            <div id="text">Pagina <span id="currentpage"></span> van <span id="pagelimit"></span></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      var sorter = new TINY.table.sorter("sorter");
        sorter.head = "head";
        sorter.asc = "asc";
        sorter.desc = "desc";
        sorter.even = "evenrow";
        sorter.odd = "oddrow";
        sorter.evensel = "evenselected";
        sorter.oddsel = "oddselected";
        sorter.paginate = true;
        sorter.currentid = "currentpage";
        sorter.limitid = "pagelimit";
        sorter.init("table",1);
      </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

And my process file

```
<?php
include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$safeid = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query = mysql_query("delete from units where id=$id", $con);
?>
```

Comment: i don't see any buttons in your code

Comment: Open your browser debugger (built in in Chrome and otherwise Firebug) and see what happens with the ``$.post`` that should be sent. Maybe it is something basic such as wrong path or parameters.

Comment: Here is how in Firebug: https://getfirebug.com/network and here is how in Chrome: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find the parent of the `a`, you are finding the `td`. This would explain why you are seeing the `td` disappear instead of the `tr`.

For this reason, instead of `parent()`, use `closest("tr")` to find the row:

```
//var parent = $(this).parent();
var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
```

Then slideUp/remove `parent`... and you might also then want to rename `parent` to something like `parentRow`.

As for deleting the data in the database. It appears that your code is trying to find the `id` attribute of the `a`, so you'll want to make sure and have an `id` attribute in `a` that matches the id you'd want to delete from the db... something like `<a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" ...  />`

**Another solution**, if you want to be able to click anywhere in the row (since you mentioned trying it) you could do this:

```
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('tr').click(function () {
            //this assumes id will always be within the first td
            //you could also put classes on your td's to identify
            var del_id = $(this).find("td").first().text();
            var row = $(this);
            $.post('delete.php', {
                id: del_id
            }, function (data) {
                row.slideUp('slow', function () {
                    row.remove();
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Also a note: you should probably be more specific than just `$("a")` for this as you might have other links that you want people to be able to click without running this function.

Comment: Thank you, you var parent = $(this).closest("tr"); did the trick. I also changed the a into a variable :). Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by changing the `a` into a variable, so I just want to make sure that you understood what I meant. You could put a class on the `a`'s that you want to be able to click to remove a row like `<a href="#" class="hidesRow" ... >` and then use a selector like `$("a.hidesRow")`. If you are sure there are no links in tables that you don't want this to happen for, you could also just check that it is actually within a table cell like this `$("td a")`

Comment: Oww sorry for the misunderstanding. But i added a class too it indeed.